# Alfresco Configuration to Eclipse or by Maven

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, archetypes

I am trying to configure the development environment for Alfresco version 5.0.b.
i have tried as per the documentation for maven and also tried by my way in eclipse but i am facing an issue with both like

if i do it by maven from command prompt like

> C:\maven_projects\project_1>mvn install 
>   [INFO] Scanning for
>   projects... Downloading:
>   https   ://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/alfresco/maven/alfresco-sd
>   k-parent/2.0.0-beta-4/alfresco-sdk-parent-2.0.0-beta-4.pom [ERROR] The
>   build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1] [ERROR] [ERROR]   The
>   project ipr.res.in:project_1:1.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\maven_projects\proje
>   ct_1\pom.xml) has 1 error [ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could
>   not transfer artifact org.alfresco.
>   maven:alfresco-sdk-parent:pom:2.0.0-beta-4 from/to central
>   (https:    //repo.maven.a pache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org and
>   'parent.relativePath' points at wro ng local POM @ line 12, column 13:
>   Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org -> [Help 2 ] [ERROR] [ERROR] To see
>   the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit ch.
>   [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>   [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible
>   solutions, please rea d the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http:  //cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildin
>   gException [ERROR] [Help 2]
>   http:  //cwiki.apache.org   /confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableMo
>   delException C:\maven_projects\project_1>

If i try in eclipse 
i create one project as maven project in that i add the catalog file with maven central for the url (http:   //repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml) but when i try to import the archetype (org.alfresco. ..) it is not giving me anything.

So kindly help me out for the issue to configure the AMP

### My Project POM.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http:   //maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http:   //www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http:   //maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http:  //maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.alfresco.tutorials</groupId>
<artifactId>quick-start-project</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>quick-start-project Repository AMP project</name>
<packaging>amp</packaging>
<description>Manages the lifecycle of the quick-start-project Repository AMP (Alfresco Module Package)</description>

<parent>
<groupId>org.alfresco.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>alfresco-sdk-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0-beta-4</version>
</parent>

<!-- 
| SDK properties have sensible defaults in the SDK parent,
| but you can override the properties below to use another version. 
| For more available properties see the alfresco-sdk-parent POM. 
-->
<properties>
<!--
| Defines the groupId for the Alfresco Artifacts to work against. As of 4.2 the only allowed value is: org.alfresco
| NOTE: See http:  //docs.alfresco.com/4.2/concepts/dev-extensions-maven-sdk-tutorials-alfresco-enterprise.html for details
-->
<alfresco.groupId>org.alfresco</alfresco.groupId>
<!-- Defines the Alfresco version to work against.
Community versions are typically identified by major.minor.character (4.2.a) while Enterprise versions are identified by major.minor.digit (4.2.0)  -->
<alfresco.version>5.0.a</alfresco.version>
<app.log.root.level>WARN</app.log.root.level>
<alfresco.data.location>alf_data_dev</alfresco.data.location>
<!-- Defines the target WAR artifactId to run this amp, only used with the -Pamp-to-war switch
.    | Allowed values: alfresco | share. Defaults to a repository AMP, but could point to your foundation WAR -->
<alfresco.client.war>alfresco</alfresco.client.war>
<!-- Defines the target WAR groupId to run this amp, only used with the -Pamp-to-war switch
.    | Could be org.alfresco or your corporate groupId -->
<alfresco.client.war.groupId>org.alfresco</alfresco.client.war.groupId>
<!-- Defines the target WAR version to run this amp, only used with the -Pamp-to-war switch -->
<alfresco.client.war.version>5.0.a</alfresco.client.war.version>
<!-- This controls which properties will be picked in src/test/properties for embedded run -->
<env>local</env>
</properties>

<!-- Here we realize the connection with the Alfresco selected platform 
(e.g.version and edition) -->
<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
<!-- This will import the dependencyManagement for all artifacts in the selected Alfresco version/edition
(see http:  //maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies) 
NOTE: You still need to define dependencies in your POM, but you can omit version as it's enforced by this dependencyManagement. NOTE: It defaults 
to the latest version this SDK pom has been tested with, but alfresco version can/should be overridden in your project's pom -->
<dependency>
<groupId>${alfresco.groupId}</groupId>
<artifactId>alfresco-platform-distribution</artifactId>
<version>${alfresco.version}</version>
<type>pom</type>
<scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<!-- Following dependencies are needed for compiling Java code in src/main/java; 
<scope>provided</scope> is inherited for each of the following; 
for more info, please refer to alfresco-platform-distribution POM -->
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>${alfresco.groupId}</groupId>
<artifactId>alfresco-repository</artifactId>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

---

Comment: IIRC the Alfresco poms and artifacts are only available from the Alfresco maven repo, not central. What happens if you list the Alfresco maven repo servers as well in your pom?

Comment: I am Using the Maven central name of the catalog with the link http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml

Comment: I am trying to configure in eclipse like this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=utYZaVe9Nd0 where i am not gettting the list when i put org.alfresco in filter name..

Comment: I have also given the parent relativePath in pom file located in my project folder but when i am trying mvn install it does not take the relativepath ..

Comment: I'd suggest you post your POM in the question, so we can see what you are doing

Answer (score 3):

As the Maven error message explains, the Alfresco Maven SDK is not available in Maven central. It is only available from the [Alfresco Artifacts Maven repository](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_Artifacts_Repository)

You therefore need to add this snippet into your pom:

```
<repositories> 
  <repository>     
    <id>alfresco-public</id>      
    <url>https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>   
  </repository>  
</repositories>
```

You can find out more from the [Alfresco Maven SDK wiki page](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Maven_Alfresco_SDK) and the [Alfresco Artifacts Maven Repository wiki page](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_Artifacts_Repository)